# Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string in Maven project

Tags: java, linux, maven

I was learning Maven. I created a basic example in IntelliJ to print a "Hello Maven.!!", but when I was trying to run its failing with `Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string in Maven project`.

I am using ,

1. jdk: 15.0.1
2. OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello Maven.!!");
    }
}
```

POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>AgainMaven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Error:

```
Executing pre-compile tasks...
Loading Ant configuration...
Running Ant tasks...
Abnormal build process termination: 
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-15.0.1/bin/java -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Dexternal.project.config=/home/shaquib/.cache/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.3/external_build_system/againmaven.530df6a2 -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=3974315237447359827 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=GB -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2020.3 -Didea.home.path=/snap/intellij-idea-community/264 -Didea.config.path=/home/shaquib/.config/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.3 -Didea.plugins.path=/home/shaquib/.local/share/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.3 -Djps.log.dir=/home/shaquib/.cache/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.3/log/build-log -Djps.fallback.jdk.home=/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/jbr -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=11.0.9 -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/shaquib/.cache/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.3/compile-server/againmaven_1edc3278/_temp_ -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"/tmp/kotlin-idea-300974558856897286-is-running\" -classpath /snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher /snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/annotations.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/netty-codec-4.1.52.Final.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/resources_en.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/maven-artifact-3.6.1.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/maven-resolver-util-1.3.3.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/jna.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/oro-2.0.8.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-http-1.3.3.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/gson-2.8.6.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/trove4j.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/plexus-utils-3.2.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/log4j.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/java/lib/javac2.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/netty-resolver-4.1.52.Final.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/asm-all-9.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/maven-resolver-provider-3.6.1.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/commons-lang3-3.10.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/java/lib/jps-javac-extension-1.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.25.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/maven-model-builder-3.6.1.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/httpcore-4.4.13.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/httpclient-4.5.12.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/maven-resolver-impl-1.3.3.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-connector-basic-1.3.3.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/util.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/forms-1.1-preview.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders-6.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/netty-buffer-4.1.52.Final.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/protobuf-java-3.13.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/maven-resolver-spi-1.3.3.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.6.1.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/lz4-java-1.7.1.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/netty-common-4.1.52.Final.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/maven-builder-support-3.6.1.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-file-1.3.3.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/java/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/nanoxml-2.2.3.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/maven-model-3.6.1.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/idea_rt.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/jps-model.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/maven-resolver-api-1.3.3.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/guava-29.0-jre.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/intellij-deps-fastutil-8.4.1-4.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/platform-api.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/jdom.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/plexus-component-annotations-1.7.1.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/qdox-2.0-M10.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/jna-platform.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/gson-2.8.6.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/guava-29.0-jre.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.65.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.65.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/javax.activation-1.2.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.common-27.0.0.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-api-6.7.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/gson-2.8.6.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/guava-29.0-jre.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.65.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.65.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/lib/javax.activation-1.2.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.common-27.0.0.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-api-6.7.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/java-guiForms-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-common.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-common.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/java-langInjection-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-constants-rt.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/gradle-java/lib/gradle-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-jps-common.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-common.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/android/lib/apkzlib-4.0.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/android/lib/apksig-4.0.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/android/lib/jps/android-jps-plugin.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/android/lib/android-jps-model.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/android/lib/build-common.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/android/lib/android-rt.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.sdk-common-27.0.0.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.common-27.0.0.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.repository-27.0.0.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.sdklib-27.0.0.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.layoutlib-api-27.0.0.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/264/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.manifest-merger-27.0.0.0.jar org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 40679 ff621643-197d-4bc0-bdf2-22561d786a38 /home/shaquib/.cache/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.3/compile-server
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-15.0.1/bin/java: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Executing post-compile tasks...
Loading Ant configuration...
Running Ant tasks...
Synchronizing output directories...
25/11/20, 10:02 AM - Build completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 1 sec, 538 ms
```

Could you please help to resolve it?

Comment: What else does the error say?

Comment: @VladL I have added the complete error message. Could you please check now?

Comment: The code you pasted works on my machine :) I used openJDK 15.0.1 Make sure you don't have any new lines in between your quotes and try to rebuild the project.

Comment: Thanks @VladL, It working with other jdk, but not with oracle jdk15. Not sure why. I have switched to a lower version now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had a similar issue recently with java 17. Make sure you have downloaded the correct version of your jdk.
I had downloaded the Linux / AArch64 instead of the Linux / x64, giving me the exact same message as you.

Comment: AArch! Who in their right mind places the binary release for ARM above that for x64? Thanks. Uh, you can check by going to the Java install folder and then type `file bin\java`. It'll tell you the architecture. Thanks for this answer, that was unexpected.